# Fetch Field Label in Lightning Web Components

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using `uiRecordApi` to fetch record from the database, to provide static binding I am using fields using schema.

```
import  MAX_LTV from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Max_LTV__c';
```

All works, but am not able to fetch the Label of the field, printing `MAX_LTV` only gives API Name.

```
{fieldApiName: "Max_LTV__c", objectApiName: "Opportunity"}
```

The  reason being, now I have records and fields, but not label to dynamically iterate and display on-screen using `template-for`,

is there a way or I have to use apex for it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You will get the labels of all fields in [getObjectInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_object_info). You should use `data.fields.fieldName.label`

Below is the sample code to get label of `CloseDate` field in `Opportunity`.

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT })
    oppInfo({ data, error }) {
        if (data) console.log('CloseDate Label => ', data.fields.CloseDate.label);
    }

}
```

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thanks :)