# Instantiate object and prepopulate field values to show as output field LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a custom object Child__c which looks up to Account. I am overriding New button of that Child__c. I am working in Classic and on click of New, I need to show some fields from Account and some fields from Child__c. I am using lightning-record-edit-form for this. Now what I am stuck at is I want to show a field of Child__c (Child_Field__c) as output field and I want to populate it's value from Account field. I already have the Account field value but don't know how I can instantiate Child__c and store the value I have in Child_Field__c and show as output field.

I Googled it and tried couple of links but it is not working. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_example
[Fetch Field Label in Lightning Web Components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/277793/fetch-field-label-in-lightning-web-components)

Can anyone suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of **value** attribute of [lightning-input-field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/documentation) to prepopulate a field with default value and use **disabled** attribute to make it read only.

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Child__c">
        <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Account__c"></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Child_Field__c" value={valueFromAccount} disabled></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand"
            type="submit" name="update" label="Update">
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>        
</template>
```

Comment: Hi Sanket, I appreciate it and tried this, but it is showing grey colored background for disabled text box and I also have a lookup field of account. It shows as grey background and account icon. I can make the change from CSS but while this is a hack, we have a whole team checking for the best practices. So, do you have any other solution to this?

Comment: And if we try to modify the CSS by adding a .css file, LWC has limitation. Just saw this article. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279878/overwrite-standard-lightning-web-component-css-by-class-name

Comment: accepted the answer as there seem to be no alternate to this at the moment. Thank you for answering and for your blogs as well! Really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you @JigarTrivedi