# How to get field label from metadata in LWC (lightning web component)

Tags: lightning-web-components, fields, label

I want to get a field label from metadata.  In this usage, it isn't part of data.  I just want the label for elsewhere on the page.  Getting it from metadata instead of hardcoding it will aid in translatibility.

In Apex, I would code --

```
SObjectType.MyObject__c.fields.MyField__c.getLabel()
```

In VisualForce, I'd code --

```
{!$ObjectType.MyObject__c.Fields.MyField__c.Label}
```

I'm preferring whatever is analogous to the VisualForce solution as I really don't want to have to go to the Apex controller just to get labels.

I found this thread from four years ago which uses the UI api, I suppose that may be one way but I'm wondering if it's improved since then and there is a more efficient way.

[Get Object Label from API Name in LWC using wire](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289073/get-object-label-from-api-name-in-lwc-using-wire)

Comment: The method in your link is how we are doing it... The platform does have the chance of caching this data at the client-side making the access fast if several components are using it. But yes, it is quite a lot of boiler plate code for a common situation.

Comment: working example using objectinfo method - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/277793/fetch-field-label-in-lightning-web-components

Comment: getObjectInfo is the intended solution. In isolation, it looks wasteful, but considering that the same calls are used all over the UI and can be aggregated into a single network call is a win for overall performance by reducing memory and bandwidth usage.